# ms sql server on mac os x with docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I want to run sql-server on a mac os x computer. I have successfully build and start a docker container this way:

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
docker create -v /var/opt/mssql --name volume_mssql microsoft/mssql-server-linux /bin/true
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=SuperPa3ss@1' -p 1433:1433 --volumes-from volume_mssql -d --name sqlserver1 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

It works fine. But i do not know what to do to restart this containers when the computer restarts...

Thanks

** edit **

if i type:

```
$ docker start volume_mssql
$ docker start sqlserver1
```

I have no error message, but i see the containers are "exited"

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
f5721868bbe1        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/mss…"   15 hours ago        Exited (255) 3 minutes ago                       sqlserver1
e5b88bb02a1b        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/true"              15 hours ago        Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                         volume_mssql
```

** edit **

```
$ docker container logs sqlserver1
Dump collecting thread [6] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
Dump collecting thread [7] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
```

Comment: The container was given a name when you created it. Use `docker start thatname` to start it again. You can find the name with `docker ps` or `docker ps -a`

Comment: Also check [Start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/) from Docker's docs

Answer (score 2):

For Autostart, docker container adds `--restart always` in docker run command.

Change your command to:

> docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=SuperPa3ss@1' --restart always -p 1433:1433 --volumes-from volume_mssql -d --name sqlserver1 microsoft/mssql-server-linux

Your container will start automatically when you restart the docker and PC.

Answer (score 1):

**From Terminal:**

```
$ docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux

$ docker run -d — name sql_server_demo -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=Dev@998877’ -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux

$ dokcer image ls
```

Now Download azure data studio from here, 
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

**Connect to SQL Server** 
 
Server: localhost 
 
Authentication Type: SQL Login  
 
User Name: sa  
 
Password: Dev@99887

**Steps by steps:** 
 
https://medium.com/macoclock/run-mssql-on-mac-using-docker-39460da701b9

Answer (score 0):

You can find the container name by running: `docker ps -a` and use the name to start it using `docker start <container-name>`.

Alternatively, you can specify the container to start automatically by adding `--restart always` to the run command. This will make the container autostart once you restart the PC.

Comment: @Bob5421 check the container logs `docker container logs <container-name>`